# Updating a SQL record with Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell

It's me again, I'm still getting to limited grips about how PowerShell and SQL work together, this isn't my main field of experience so please excuse the simple mistake I've probably made.

I am trying to update one field in a row.  I've searched here and been able to build most of what I need but am getting an error message that states

"Exception calling "ExecuteNonQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Incorrect syntax near 'f7'."
At line:61 char:5
+     $rowsAffected = $command2.ExecuteNonQuery()
+     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [], MethodInvocationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : SqlException"

This is the code snippet I am using is this section, it is embedded within a foreach loop that steps through the rows of a dataset and sends an email.  This section is supposed to change the bit type field "mailed" to true which ensure that only one email is sent per record.

```
$connect2 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$connect2.ConnectionString=$ServerConnection
$connect2.Open()
$command2 = New-Object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand
$command2.Connection = $connect2
$MySql2="UPDATE dbo.scans SET Mailed = 'True' WHERE SessionID ="+$BT1
$command2.CommandText = $MySql2
$rowsAffected = $command2.ExecuteNonQuery()
Write-Output "Updating mailed marker"
$connect2.Close()
```

EBGreen's suggestion worked perfectly.  Changing the text string for the $MySql2 = "UPDATE dbo.scans SET Mailed = 'True' WHERE SessionID ='"+$BT1+"'" fixed the error and the field is being updated as required.

Comment: I suspect that you need quotes around the SessionID. I don't know this for a fact thus the comment not answer. Try: ***$MySql2="UPDATE dbo.scans SET Mailed = 'True' WHERE SessionID ='"+$BT1+"'"***

Comment: Honestly, I find easier and better to generate a `.sql` file with powershell, then execute the file on specified database by doing `C:> mysql -uuser -ppassword -hhost -Ddatabase < out.sql`. I find interfacing directly to be clunky

Comment: That is cool, but I'm not sure the OP is using mysql. As a matter of fact I'm pretty sure they aren't since they are using a SQL-Server object for the query.

Comment: @EBGreen Thanks that worked perfectly.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Try displaying your sql string to make sure it looks correct.  It could be that your $BT1 variable is blank.

```
write-host $MySql2
```

Also, when dealing with sql syntax errors it is helpful to log in directly to the sql server and submit the string through the sql command line shell.  Once you can submit the string successfully from the command line then check that your powershell string looks exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can make your query string setup more basic. Within PowerShell if you reference a variable with double-quotes, PowerShell will resolve that variable to the set value.

So instead of doing this:

```
$MySql2="UPDATE dbo.scans SET Mailed = 'True' WHERE SessionID ="+$BT1
```

Or even this:

```
$MySql2="UPDATE dbo.scans SET Mailed = 'True' WHERE SessionID ='"+$BT1+"'"
```

You can simply do this:

```
$MySql2="UPDATE dbo.scans SET Mailed = 'True' WHERE SessionID ='$BT1'"
```

[image]